# Relations between isomorphic Galois Groups and Norms

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K,L,M$ and $T$ be a fields. Suppose that $K/L$ and $T/M$ are galois extensions, and define $G=Gal(K/L)$ and $H=Gal(T/M)$ with $G\cong H$.

Consider $\alpha \in K$ such that $f(\alpha) \in T$ for some $f \in M[x]$.

Is $N_{T/M}(f(\alpha))=f(N_{K/L}(\alpha))?$

Comment: You haven't specified any relationship between $K$ and $M$, so what does it mean to apply a polynomial $f \in M[x]$ to an element $\alpha \in K$?

Comment: Ok. We can think that every field in the question is a number field.

Comment: Okay. Then this is already false even in the special case where $L = M$ and $K = T$; that is, speaking just in terms of $K/L$, it's already false that $N_{K/L}(f(\alpha)) = f(N_{K/L}(\alpha))$ where $f \in L[x]$. For example take $L = \mathbb{Q}, K = \mathbb{Q}[i], \alpha = 1, f(x) = x + 1$.

Comment: Did you mean $\sigma(f(\alpha)) = f(\varphi(\alpha))$  ?